Error 500 on the Heroku server, when locally everything is fine
I made an django app from the "Python Crush Course" book and
when I try to login or register in my django app on heroku server, I
have an error 500 on webpage and error 200 on logs. However, when I register or login locally I don't
have any issues.
Here are the heroku logs:
2024-08-02T22:17:13.267743+00:00 heroku\[web.1\]: State changed from starting to up
2024-08-03T22:34:20.389130+00:00 heroku\[router\]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=fierce-brook-34882-87d6631e0056.herokuapp.com request_id=34b832f3-b190-4bc2-88ac-576c6dd59905 fwd="80.107.58.61" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=137ms status=200 bytes=2493 protocol=https
2024-08-03T22:34:20.389210+00:00 app\[web.1\]: - - \[03/Aug/2024:22:34:20 +0000\] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2197 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:128.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/128.0"
2024-08-03T22:34:20.729350+00:00 app\[web.1\]: 10.1.62.231 - - \[03/Aug/2024:22:34:20 +0000\] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 1862 "https://fierce-brook-34882-87d6631e0056.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:128.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/128.0"
2024-08-03T22:34:20.729672+00:00 heroku\[router\]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fierce-brook-34882-87d6631e0056.herokuapp.com request_id=ba080178-f0ef-4d0c-8745-0556273710f1 fwd="80.107.58.61" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=28ms status=404 bytes=2165 protocol=https
2024-08-03T22:34:26.884713+00:00 app\[web.1\]: 10.1.94.152 - - \[03/Aug/2024:22:34:26 +0000\] "GET /users/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2715 "https://fierce-brook-34882-87d6631e0056.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:128.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/128.0"

Here are the localhosts logs:
[arch@archlinux dj_proj]$ python3 manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 14, 2024 - 19:36:06
Django version 5.1, using settings 'learning_log.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

[14/Aug/2024 19:36:09] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2197
[14/Aug/2024 19:36:28] "GET /users/register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6332
[14/Aug/2024 19:36:30] "GET /users/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2715
[14/Aug/2024 19:37:57] "POST /users/login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[14/Aug/2024 19:37:57] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2574
[14/Aug/2024 19:38:02] "POST /users/logout/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1835
[14/Aug/2024 19:38:04] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2197

I also tried
heroku run python
and this is not working
Edit: I rewrote the entire project and now everything working. Thanks to all who tried to help me.

What do you intend to get from heroku run python?

Your logs don't show the errors you are talking about. You might need better logging if you are getting 500 errors (internal errors in your app). Or is there logging you aren't sharing here? Is six lines actually the full extent of all your heroku logs?

@Hocuda Not sure why you’ve included local logs if the problem isn’t local. Your Heroku logs also show that you got a 200 response for a GET request to /users/login, so where are you actually seeing 500 errors?
